# MSSQL difference between databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

- We have web-app, which is connected to MS SQL server.
  In database (lets call it Prod-database) we keep configuration of our app (Some tables with       access rights etc) and information about our clients. During the day we get new clients and orders.
- Main idea is to update our app to next patch.
  Update process(With testing) takes something around 12 hours.
  Problem is that we don't want to lose data about clients during the "update day"
- So we decided, that we won't do anything with Prod-database during the day. It will work as usual.

That is the update process (Productive app is working):

1. At the begging of "update day" we will create another database using Prod-database backup, let's call it Test-Database.
2. We deploy second app using Test-Database.
3. We Update Test-Database
4. During the day, we test new patch
5. After successful testing we need to update difference (Information about clients) between Test-Database and Prod-database
6. We backup Test-database
7. Restore Prod-database from Test-database backup
8. And we are updated

And the main question is: How to properly transmit the difference?
considering that data in Prod-database can be updated and inserted, not deleted.

- Using for new data: Select * FROM [Prod-database].[Order] INTO Test-Database.[Order] Where CreatedOn = [CurrentDate]
- Using for modified data: Update [Test-Database.].[Order] SET [Test-Database].[Order].[AnyColumn] = [Prod-database].[Order].[AnyColumn] FROM [Prod-database].[Order] Where [Prod-database].[Order].Id = [Test-Database].[Order].Id AND [Prod-database].[Order].ModifiedOn = [CurrentDate]

Or there is some other, more effective way, maybe replication or using snapshots..
Could you please explain me the way to do it
I am new to such DBA tasks, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: One typically upgrades production databases by running DDL and data migration scripts, not with restore.

Comment: If your database has a `ModifiedOn` and `CreatedOn` then you've answered your own question - to apply data drift, you capture all records with `ModifiedDate` and `CreatedOn` after your snapshot and apply them, exactly like you have posted.

Comment: The notion of restoring a test database over the prod database is the kind of thing that will keep you awake at night in a cold sweat. I don't care how diligent you are that is the wrong way to go. You need to create a deployment script that will update any object changes to the production database in place. To test your script you restore production to a QA server, apply your script and test everything. Then when you are satisfied you apply that same script to prod.

Comment: I use the [Schema Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver15) in Visual Studio to do this from different instances as well as TFS source control to track changes in your database.